# c++ how to create classes that are interdependent

Tags: c++, class

I have a storage class. members of this class are often modified.
each time a member is modified, I'd like to save the state of the class (clone class instance and save it).
So I'd like to create a new class, that will save these states.

For Example:

Say I have a Storage class in file storage.h

```
class Storage 
{
 public:
   Int m_cnt;
   <lots of other members...>

   StorageHistory m_his;
};
```

and a StorageHistory class in file storagehistory.h

```
class StorageHistory 
{
 public:
   std::vector<Storage> m_history_vec;
};
```

Assumptions:

1. `StorageHistory` class should be kept in Storage class. the reason for that is that `Storage` class is a main class that can be accessed in all classes/packages. to minimize the changes in the code, I'd like S`torageHistory` to be coupled with `Storage` class.
2. `StorageHistory` cannot be static or singleton since multiple instance of `Storage` are created.

Problems:

1. Cannot compile this code. storage.h needs to be compiled before storagehistory.h and vice versa
2. If `StorageHistory` cannot be stored in `Storage` class then were do I keep it? who is the owner of this class?

Need help to define the connection between these two classed?

Comment: Have you tried using forward declarations?

Comment: @user1798187 Hehe. I thought you are sharing `m_his` in multiple instances. Sorry. :)

Comment: Why not make Storage create a StorageHistory upon instantiation, and keep around a pointer to it? You can have both classes be aware of each other before you provide any code for either by using forward declaration.

Comment: I think a better design is define `StorageHistory` as a internal class of Storage, because the only usage of it is recording the Storage status.Do you accept it?@user1798187

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: don't make data members public, unless you define a pure data structure. Then: `Int` is no C++ type.

Now to your questions: you can use forward declarations. Since `StorageHistory` is used directly in `Storage`, it cannot be forward declared, but `Storage` is only used in a template data member (namely a `std::vector`) in `StorageHistory`, and that template does not need the definition of `Storage` if it's only declared as a variable. You need the definition only when you use methods of vector.

So here's the untangled code:

StorageHistory.h

```
#include <vector>
class Storage;
class StorageHistory 
{
  std::vector<Storage> m_history_vec;
public:
  /* method declarations */
};
```

Storage.h

```
#include "StorageHistory.h"
class Storage 
{
  int m_cnt;
  /* <lots of other members...> */
  StorageHistory m_his;
public:
  /* method declarations */
};
```

Storage.cpp

```
#include "Storage.h"
#include "StorageHistory.h" //not necessarily needed, because implicitly included, but thats a matter of coding style

/* ... Storage methods definitions ... */
void Storage::changeVar(/*...*/)
{
  m_his.push_back(*this);
  /* ... */
}
```

StorageHistory.cpp

```
#include "StorageHistory.h"
#include "Storage.h"

/* ... StorageHistory method definitions ... */
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your header files

Storage.h

```
class Storage;  //to declear the class before the include

#include "StorageHistory.h"

//continue with the old declearation 

class Storage{
   ....
}
```

and

StorageHistory.h

```
class StorageHistory;  //to declear the class before the include

#include "Storage.h"

//continue with the old declearation 

class StorageHistory{
   ....
}
```

remember to have include guards first in the files.

This can be done for all classes to avoid this kind of problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially doing `memento` design pattern. Your current compilation problems will go away with forward declaration. But for better design and implementation you can see [**this**](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/memento/cpp/1) and [**this**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/186184/Memento-Design-Pattern).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use forward declarations for your solution to work. The easiest way is to put these classes in the same header file (but it may be solved a little bit differently):

```
class StorageHistory; // *** Forward declaration ***

class Storage 
{
public:
    Int m_cnt;
    &lt;lots of other members...&gt;

    StorageHistory m_his; 
};

class StorageHistory 
{
public:
    std::vector<Storage> m_history_vec;
};
```

I don't like your solution, though. The m_his will contain a list of Storage classes and all of them will contain a list of Storage classes (empty, though).

I'd create a singleton with a map of vectors of Storages and wrap a Storage with container containing an UID.

```
class StorageContainer
{
private:
    static int nextUID = 0;
    int uid;
    Storage data;

public:
    StorageContainer()
    {
        uid = nextUID++; // Watch out for concurrency problems
    }

    Storage & GetData()
    {
        return data;
    }
};
```

You could then access a history of a Storage by its UID.

```
class StorageHistory
{
    // The usual singleton stuff

    private:
        std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<Storage>> history;

    public:
        std::vector<Storage> & operator[] (int uid)
        {
            auto iter = history.find(uid);
            if (iter == unordered_map::end)
            {
                std::vector<Storage> newHistory;
                history[uid] = newHistory;
            }
            return history[uid];
        }
};
```

Comment: Quite right.Whether wrap the Storage and StorageHistory to a new class is a better solution? like: class StorageManager--has a--storage, StorageManager--has a--StorageHistory.When you call StorageManager::updateStorage, first update and than insert to StorageHistory.So you can rollback and manager history independently. @Spook

Comment: Agreed, that's an elegant solution.

Comment: @user1798187 That's a good point. I think, that this can be solved by wrapping the Storage into a container with UID: the Storage would then serve as simple data container and the logic would be shifted upwards to the containers and wrappers. What do you think?

Comment: I think that it would be better. However I think that for simplicity the above solution is sufficient enough

Comment: -1 Bad solution. Don't introduce singletons, they are in no way necessary here.